# Fast way to load data from mysql to sqlserver using SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis

I am new to SSIS is there is any component to load data from MYSQL to SQL server using SSIS. Currently am loading data using ODBC connection it is really slow and it around the speed of 30000 rows/Minute. Is there any way to make the load run fast.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: am not able to find any OLEDB connector for mysql...there is one called cherrysoft third party oledb connector for mysql that is not working fine for me...the problem am facing was connection is getting established but when am using it in SSIS while getting table name SSIS is getting crashed(closed)

Comment: Step 1: Identify the limiting factor. Is it the extract of data from MySQL, the transformations within your package, or the saving of data into your table. Without understanding that, we  have no way of knowing whether 30k rows/minute is good, bad or abysmal

Answer (score 1):

You can install the .NET Connector for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Then you can create a script task to act as a data source, import MySql.Data.MySqlClient, and query MySQL directly in C#. The data will then enter your Data Flow and you can map it to a SQL Server destination the same as normal.

I find that when using the SSIS connection manager with .Net Providers I get malformed SQL errors, but this way you write all the SQL yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance, we can add Conditional Split Transformation build some parallelism into the common data flow that directly load data from ODBC Source to OLE DB Destination.

For more information about speeding up SSIS Bulk Inserts into SQL Server, please see the following blog:
http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-ssis-bulk-inserts-into-sql-server

Answer (score -1):

In DataFlowTask property, Increase buffer size and no of row commit